# Anyway to grab author name and featured image in an embeded in inital array of posts outside of loop?

Tags: posts, wp-query

Here's how I'm doing it atm.

```
$query_vars['paged'] = $_GET['page'];
$query_vars['posts_per_page'] = $_GET['posts_per_page'];
$query_vars['post_status'] = 'publish';

$query = new WP_Query( $query_vars );

function grab($post) {
        if (isset($post)) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), "full");
            $post->featured = $image[0];
            $author = get_the_author_meta("display_name", $post->post_author);
            $post->author = $author;
        }
        return $post;
    }


    try {
        array_walk($query->posts, "grab");
        wp_send_json($query, 200);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        wp_send_json($e->getMessage(), 500);
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        wp_send_json($e->getMessage, 404);
    }


    die();
```

So this seems to work, however iterating through the returned post array and calling two more functions seems a little janky to me. Is there a better way I'm overlooking? Can I specify the meta key for author and featured post and pass them as arguments to WP_Query perhaps?

Thanks.

Comment: I do a lot of pulling in author data and other custom-field metadata into both loops and outside the loop - if you could post a bit more info about what you're doing (why outside the loop) I can probably suggest a more simplified way and offer some code to help.